# Getting context in Kotlin Adapter for getItemCount

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

I'm looking for a way to find the context of a RecyclerView Adapter outside of the viewholder methods. I have two different arrays that I would like to be able to display based on the activity/fragment that is being shown(the final app would have 4 arrays which is why I don't just want to make another adapter for each array). I can get it to work in the onbindviewholder using holder.itemview.context but since the arrays aren't the same size I need a way to use context for an if statement in getitemcount() as well. Passing context in the constructor results in "no value passed for parameter". Was wondering if anyone has found a solution to this problem using either fragments or activities. Worst case scenario I just make a different adapter for every array

```
class ItemAdapter(var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var weeklyTasks = arrayOf(R.string.app_name, R.string.daily_hint_1, R.string.daily_hint_2, R.string.daily_hint_3)
    private var dailyTasks = arrayOf(R.string.daily_hint_1, R.string.daily_hint_2, R.string.daily_hint_3)
    private var xp = intArrayOf(R.mipmap.tenxp_round, R.mipmap.fiftyxp_round, R.mipmap.hundredxp_round)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.task_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        //cant use context here because no value is passed for parameter
        return dailyTasks.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //var context = holder.itemView.context -> this works here but not as a constructor
        if(context is ToDoList) {
            holder.itemImage.setImageResource(xp[0])
            holder.itemDetail.text = dailyTasks[position].toString()
        }
        else{
            holder.itemImage.setImageResource(xp[1])
            holder.itemDetail.text = weeklyTasks[position].toString()
        }
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var itemImage: ImageView
        var itemDetail: TextView

        init {
            itemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image)
            itemDetail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Using `is` checks on a Context is a big code smell to begin with. You're mixing logic too much between code boundaries. Why don't you just have a property in the adapter's constructor that indicates which list it should show, like an enum?

Comment: That is a much better idea than what I've been trying to do! I will do that thanks